# Importing data into wit.ai

Tags: wit.ai

Update : The stackoverflow mentionned below gave another solution, namely to import the json and replace the text with the data in the right format. I am now trying to see how I can fit the format given, which looks something like this :

```
{
      "text" : "usersentence",
      "entities" : [
        {
          "entity" : "intent",
          "value" : "\"valueofintent\"",
          "start" : lenghtstart,
          "end" : lengthend
        }
      ]
}
```

---

We have a csv/json file containing a dataset we created. We are trying to import it into wit.ai without having to do it manually. I found 2 ressources online explaining a solution, but I am stuck while implementing either.

Initial link found : [How do I use wit.ai with existing rows of data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37799304/how-do-i-use-wit-ai-with-existing-rows-of-data)

The above link sent me to this one : https://github.com/wit-ai/wit-api-only-tutorial/blob/master/README.md

I can't understand how to replace the /samples he used with my own links to data. Also I can't find any info on the post/samples API he is mentionning.

Second link I found. Still unable to implement the data import: https://chunksofco.de/wit-ai-explained-part-3-building-a-bot-with-sails-js-b4b801a2f7a5

Answer (score 5):

You can simply follow the [HTTP API Reference](https://wit.ai/docs/http/20170307#post--samples-link) in wit.ai docs.

To add train data to your app, you should use `POST /samples` method in the API reference.

For example the following curl request:

```
$ TOKEN=your-wit-app-token
$ curl -XPOST 'https://api.wit.ai/samples?v=20170307' \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d '[{
        "text": "I want to fly to sfo",
        "entities": [
          {
            "entity": "intent",
            "value": "flight_request"
          },
          {
            "entity": "wit$location",
            "start": 17,
            "end": 20,
            "value": "sfo"
          }
        ]
      }]'
```

add "I want to fly to sfo" sentence with *flight_request* intent and *with$location* entity to the training data.
You can also add all of you training data in a json file `train_data.json` with the above form and use:

```
$ curl -XPOST 'https://api.wit.ai/samples?v=20170307' \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d @train_data.json
```